# Extracting multiple instances of a regex pattern from file using KornShell

Tags: regex, shell, scripting, awk, ksh

I have a file that may have multiple instances of a string pattern (starting with X ending with Y). I want to extract each instance that matching this pattern. These may be on a single line or new line may or may not be at the beginning or end of a line. I have tried using grep with a regex pattern of (X.*Y) but the version of KornShell (ksh) that is running the ksh does not recognize the -c option so having a tough time extracting what I need. I have also read that awk can do this but not finding good documentation out there for awk.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? And what does the `-c` option have to do with your question?

Comment: Please provide your sample file and expected output, it helps to understand your requirement better, thanks.

Comment: If you're using Korn shell, as your subject line suggests, you should tag this question with **ksh**, rather than **bash**.

Comment: How do you want to deal with e.g. `XabcYdefXghiY` or `XabcXdefYghiY`? Are those one match each, or two (or more)? Can matches be nested, or do you want to find only the inner/outer/first/last/largest/smallest match?

Comment: @ruifeng - I can not provide a sample file at this time just know that I'm searching a file for a pattern and want to place on instances that match the pattern into a variable to be used later.

Comment: @twalberg there will not be nested matches it will always start with X and end with Y.

Comment: @user1015196: Please edit your question, since many people will not read the comments. Say something like "I want to create a shell array with each match of this pattern", and include the other clarifications you are making in comments.

Comment: @rojomoke I've made the necessary change

Comment: @rici I want to grab (extract) the various instances of pattern matching string and put in a variable (array) to be looped through later. I mentioned -c option with grep because I didn't want someone giving me that as a possible solution when that option is not available to me. As my understanding is -c option in grep will return all instances of matching pattern and only that string and not the entire line.

Comment: @user1015196: that's the `-o` option, and it has nothing to do with the version of `ksh` that you are using. It only has to do with the version of `grep`. (And what version of grep are you using?)

Comment: @rici sorry yes my mistake I meant -o and thank you for the clarification. I had been trying multiple stuff and I think -c got stuck in my head somehow. How can I find the version? When I do a man grep I get the following: grep [ -E | -F ] [ -i ] [ -h ] [ -H ] [ -L ] [ -r | -R ] [ -s ][ -u ] [ -v ] [ -w ] [ -x ] [ -y ] [ [ [-b ] [ -n ] ] | [ -c | -l | -q ] ] [ -p [ Separator] ] { [ -e PatternList ... ] [ -f PatternFile ... ] | PatternList ... } [ File ... ]

Comment: @user1015196: You could try `grep -V`. That usually prints a version number. Note that `man grep` is not authoritative, since it might not correspond with the actual version of `grep` you are using. In case of doubt, try using `grep -o` and see if it gives an error or not.

Comment: @rici I tried grep -v and -V and neither gave me the version so unfortunately don't know the version I'm using. I had already tried -o and it told me it was not a valid option so that is why I was trying to find another way.

Comment: @user1015196: I guess you have a very old BSD grep, or perhaps you're using Solaris. (-v always means "invert the match", by the way.) In that case, there is absolutely no way you can use `grep` to match a pattern that spans more than one line. But even if you could, there's no obvious way to place the matches into a shell array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the patterns are contained on a single line, and only one instance on each line, you could try

```
awk -f ext.awk file
```

where `file` is your input file and `ext.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    pat="X.*Y"
}
$0 ~ pat {
    match ($0,"(" pat ")",a)
    print a[1]
}
```

### Update

If more than one pattern can be found on a line, or patterns extend over multiple lines, you can replace `ext.awk` with:

```
{
    line=line $0 RS
}
END {
    while(match(line,/(X[^Y]*Y)/,a)) {
        print a[1]
        line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
```

Comment: Patterns may be contained on multiple lines and may contain multiple instances

Comment: I'll try this a little later and let you know. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: so this almost works. The RegEx isn't quite right and I'm trying to figure it out but for some reason doesn't seem to be working for me. I want each occurrence of the X...Y. So XabcdYzzzXddddYXhhhhY should return XabcdY and XddddY and XhhhhY but the RegEx is getting greedy and giving me XabcdYzzzXddddYXhhhhY. I've tried X.*?Y and X(.*?)Y but they don't seem to be working for me. Any suggestions on the regex?

Comment: Adding to this between each X and Y there may be a special character for example X*abc*1YXabacY

Comment: It works for me using `X[^Y]*Y` as regex. I get `XabcdY`, `XddddY`, and `XhhhhY`..

Comment: strange I must have had a typo somewhere retyping it again I get the correct results. Thank you very much!!